# Using API key with node js google library

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to consume google youtube data apis which has support for api key type of credentials.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

I am trying to use google auth library for node js to communicate with the apis

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs

There is an example of this API with oAuth credentials and service account credentials.

I know that api key is supposed to be used by client side applications like browser based javascripts. So i see example with browser based google apis.

But is there any example where api keys can be used with google node js client library ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Google API NodeJS client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) using an API key on NodeJS. Just put the API key instead of the oauth client in the `auth` field :

```javascript
"use strict"

const {google} = require('googleapis');

const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
});

youtube.search.list({
    part: 'id,snippet',
    q: 'Node.js on Google Cloud',
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});;
```

There is [this internal check](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-googleapis-common/blob/ca5178382046e1f1d365cd37d60bb508febf3db8/src/apirequest.ts#L223-L227) in `google-api-commons` nodejs library which check if `auth` is a string and add the API key to the request in that case.